# Android finger paint

Tags: android, paint

I m developing an application to paint the the canvas using finger stroke with the help of FingerPaint application given at the [site](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/FingerPaint.html) Here one of the recently drawn color overlap the color previously drawn at same palce. Is there any way to limit one or two color that doesn't get overlapped by other In other words if i had drawn red(or any that user wants) color on canvas then none of the color should hide this it will show ever n ever.Let me know if the problem is not clear to you

thanks in advance,..

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GLSurface you can use the normal method of GL pixel manipulation - in particular, getPixels().  There are many ways to have fun with pixels in GL - you can add blending, scaling, etc and even convert the existing canvas into a texture on a model in the scene.

If you are not using a GLSurface... someone else will need to help. :)

Comment: thanks....I can try the OpenGL, Can u tell me the tutorial that belong to exactly these functionality or any hint related to do this..